# how to filter array of objects based upon timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, momentjs

I have more than 1 thousand  array of objects and every object inside the array contains date and time fileds. This records  are inserted to DB for every seconds as shown below. Here I want get pas 7 days record including minutes and seconds based upon **current date+hours+seconds**.

Example:

```
[{
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:45:58",
    "energy": 29940913188,
    "power": 6783,
    "time": 217781102
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:01",
    "energy": 29940913267,
    "power": 6792,
    "time": 217781105
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:02",
    "energy": 29940913318,
    "power": 6791,
    "time": 217781107
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:04",
    "energy": 29940913344,
    "power": 6797,
    "time": 217781108
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:05",
    "energy": 29940913396,
    "power": 6816,
    "time": 217781110
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:07",
    "energy": 29940913421,
    "power": 6798,
    "time": 217781111
}, {
    "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:08",
    "energy": 29940913473,
    "power": 6804,
    "time": 217781113
}]
```

Please let me know how can I do this by using JS or jquery

Comment: Does this array is dynamic i.e. are objects inserted into it continuously after some interval ?

Comment: Please explain more your time format.

Comment: You can try my below answer to filter as you expected. Have you had a chance to look at this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the filter as below to achieve this.

```
data.filter((d) => {
  return new Date(d.date).getTime() >= seventhDay.getTime();
});
```

Here, if your `date` data type is `Date` already, you don't need to convert to date again `new Date(d.date)`.

Also, it will work without `getTime()` as below.

```
return new Date(d.date) >= seventhDay;
```

```js
var data=[{"date":"11/20/2016 08:45:58","energy":29940913188,"power":6783,"time":217781102},{"date":"11/25/2016 08:46:01","energy":29940913267,"power":6792,"time":217781105},{"date":"11/25/2016 08:46:02","energy":29940913318,"power":6791,"time":217781107},{"date":"11/25/2016 08:46:04","energy":29940913344,"power":6797,"time":217781108},{"date":"11/25/2016 08:46:05","energy":29940913396,"power":6816,"time":217781110},{"date":"11/25/2016 08:46:07","energy":29940913421,"power":6798,"time":217781111},{"date":"11/21/2016 08:46:08","energy":29940913473,"power":6804,"time":217781113}]

var seventhDay = new Date();
seventhDay.setDate(seventhDay.getDate() - 7);

var filteredData = data.filter((d) => {
  return new Date(d.date).getTime() >= seventhDay.getTime();
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: This works well, when the date is not within the first week of a month for sure. I m not quite sure, if this works when the current date is 12/01/2016

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this.

```js
var input = [{
  "date": "11/22/2016 08:45:58",
  "energy": 29940913188,
  "power": 6783,
  "time": 217781102
}, {
  "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:01",
  "energy": 29940913267,
  "power": 6792,
  "time": 217781105
}, {
  "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:02",
  "energy": 29940913318,
  "power": 6791,
  "time": 217781107
}, {
  "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:04",
  "energy": 29940913344,
  "power": 6797,
  "time": 217781108
}, {
  "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:05",
  "energy": 29940913396,
  "power": 6816,
  "time": 217781110
}, {
  "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:07",
  "energy": 29940913421,
  "power": 6798,
  "time": 217781111
}, {
  "date": "11/25/2016 08:46:08",
  "energy": 29940913473,
  "power": 6804,
  "time": 217781113
}];

function filter(format) {
  return input.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.date.indexOf(format) !== -1;
  });
}

var last7Days = getLast7Days();
var results = last7Days.map((date) => {
  return filter(date);
}).filter((result) => {
  return result.length != 0
});

console.log(...results);


function pad(number) {
  if (number < 10) {
    return '0' + number;
  }
  return number;
}

function getLast7Days() {
  var output = [];
  for (var idx = 0; idx < 7; idx++) {

    var date = new Date();
    var last = new Date(date.getTime() - ((idx + 1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var day = pad(last.getDate());
    var month = pad(last.getMonth() + 1);
    var year = last.getFullYear();

    output.push(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
  }
  console.log(output);
  return output;
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants the past 7 days record and not just the one.

Comment: Modified the snippet.